# How to initialize a std::array inside of a template class?

Tags: c++, embedded

I would like to initialize the array inside the `BitSet` class with zero values using the default constructor, according to the `aLen` template value.

Eg:
`MyClass<8> myClass;` <= this object should have an array of 8 bytes, all initialized to zero.
`MyClass<16> myClass;` <= this object should have an array of 16 bytes, all initialized to zero.

```
template <size_t aLen>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass()
        {

        }
    private:
        std::array<gsl::byte, aLen> mArray;
};
```

I expect the array to be initialized to zeros.

Comment: `std::array<byte, aLen> mArray{};`

Comment: Also, you should change `MyClass() { }` to `MyClass() = default;` or just remove it completely and let the compiler auto-generate it.

Comment: The type is not a std::byte but a gsl::byte, sorry for that

Answer (score 7):

`std::array` can be initialized to zero just like a built-in array. E.g. via aggregate/value initialization in a default member initializer:

```
std::array<std::byte, aLen> mArray{};
```